Varanasi pilgrimage tour for 2 days - what are some must visits/dos?
I could only stay in Varanasi for 2 days in November. I have no interest in shopping or tourism.
Purely from pilgrimage purposes, what are some things you recommend I see/experience?

Not sure if this is the right forum. Manikarnika ghat and Kashi Vishvanath temple.

thanks a lot!!!
